# Difference between 'during', 'in' and 'of'

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

> ***Incorrect:*** Whereas it had been possible to at least consider the draft proposal of the directors, none of the two options of the final
>   bargaining round were acceptable because of the bulk of the finance
>   stipulated in the fine print depended on output.
>
> ***Correct:*** Whereas it had been possible to at least consider the draft proposal of the directors, **neither** of the two options
>   **during** the final bargaining round **was** acceptable **because the bulk** of the finance stipulated in the fine print depended on output.

The above-mentioned question is from GMAT. This question is based on subject-verb related. But my question is related to preposition, that is,

1. Why did they use ***during*** instead of ***of***?
2. Is it fine if I use ***in*** instead of ***of***?. If so, what is
   the difference I am making here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think **of** is strictly wrong in this sentence, but its meaning is vague. Do the options "belong to" the round? Possibly, but it's more accurate to say that the options were proposed **during** the final round. As you suggest, **in** is also a better choice than **of**. One of the definitions of **in** is this: "expressing a period of time during which an event takes place or a situation remains the case." So it's similar to **during** in this case.